# Custom GCMBroadcastReceiver

Tags: android

I currently create a broadcastreceiver like this:
In my fragment:

```
receiver=new GcmBroadcastReceiverLobby();
IntentFilter filter =new IntentFilter("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE");
filter.setPriority(9999);
filter.addAction("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE");
getActivity().registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

class GcmBroadcastReceiverLobby extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        String messageType = extras.toString();
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
        abortBroadcast();
    }
}
```

The problem is intent.getExtras doesn't return the details from the GCM-Message.

```
<receiver
        android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

            <category android:name="de.battlestr1k3.gamelobbies" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".GcmIntentService" android:exported="true" />
```

The GcmBroadcastReceiverLobby has a higher priority so it catches the notification first. I might be missing a permission in the code?

```
extras.toString()
```

returns Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=280]

Answer (score 0):

Ok I added

```
if (!extras.isEmpty()) {
```

}
and it worked